# Android Library - When I import libraries containing each other, is the same library added to the project more than once?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-library, android-module

I have `:a`, `:b` and `:c` libraries in an android project and I am submitting them separately to GitLab as maven repos.

The :a library imports the :b library.

```
implementation(":b")
```

The :b library imports the :c library.

```
implementation(":c")
```

In my `:app` application, I import `:a`, `:b` and `:c` libraries via GitLab.

```
implementation(":a")
implementation(":b")
implementation(":c")
```

In this case, a dependency occurs in the `:app` application as follows.

:a (contains :b (contains :c) )
:b (contains :c)
:c

---

In this case, am I creating an extra extra dependency? Will there be 1x `:a`, 2x `:b`, 3x `:c` libraries in the `:app` application? We don't want this.

If we set the `:a`, `:b` and `:c` libraries so that they do not see each other, will we create a healthier build structure?

Comment: You can not import a library more than once (otherwise the class and package names would collide), thus Gradle handles the dependencies and and only imports `:c` only once.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have 2x :b or 3x :c modules in your application.

You should [refer to the android libraries docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations). you can also check the [modules docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ApplicationModules)